# What is the significance of type parameter? Why we need to add it in the return type once and then also between the modifier and return type?

Tags: java, generics

Consider this generic method taken from `Effective Java:`

```
  // Generic method
    public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) {
     Set<E> result = new HashSet<E>(s1);
     result.addAll(s2);
     return result;
    }
```

And this method to to exercise the generic method above :

```
// Simple program to exercise generic method
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Set<String> guys = new HashSet<String>(
 Arrays.asList("Tom", "Dick", "Harry"));
 Set<String> stooges = new HashSet<String>(
 Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly"));
 Set<String> aflCio = union(guys, stooges); //What does the type parameter help here?
 System.out.println(aflCio);
}
```

if we didn't provide the type parameter ie `<E>` between the modifier and the return type can we still not assign the reference `aflCio` which is of type `Set<String>` to the return value of union method ? What is the type parameter buying us here ?

I am having difficulty understanding the following paragraph:

> One noteworthy feature of generic methods is that you needn’t specify
>   the value of the type parameter explicitly as you must when invoking
>   generic con- structors. The compiler figures out the value of the type
>   parameters by examining the types of the method arguments. In the case
>   of the program above, the compiler sees that both arguments to union
>   are of type Set, so it knows that the type parameter E must be
>   String. This process is called type inference.

Are we not mentioning the type parameter in the return type as `Set<E>`. So why do we need to add it again ?

Comment: The type parameter (together with the rest of the generics system) buys you type safety: As long as you have no warnings in your entire code base, the type system provided by generics is a strong guarantee. Without generics you could return a `Set` containing `Integer`, `String` and `HashMap` objects all mixed into one.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I want to understand how this type parameter is providing type safety . Can you explain please ?

Comment: without the parameter, how could you ensure that you're creating an appropriate `Set<String>`? You could only create a `Set<?> ` or `Set<Object>` or a raw `Set`. None of those would give you the necessary guarantees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to understand this is to consider the alternatives. Without using a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html), one would have to choose a suitable type for the `Set`.

`Object` is not a valid choice, because you don't want to receive a `Set<Object>` from your method - you can't assign that to a `Set<String>`:

```
// Nope 
public static Set<Object> union(Set<Object> s1, Set<Object> s2) {
  Set<Object> result = new HashSet<Object>(s1);
  result.addAll(s2);
  return result;
}
```

Nor is a wildcard `?` type appropriate. Again, you are unable to assign this to a `Set<String>`.

Instead, Java has defined a syntax for a generic method which is designed for exactly this scenario.

```
public static <E> Set<E> union(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2) {
  Set<E> result = new HashSet<E>(s1);
  result.addAll(s2);
  return result;
}
```

Now we don't care what type is stored in the `Set`, provided the same type is used in both inputs. The compiler then knows the return type will be `Set<String>` if the inputs are `Set<String>`s.

Comment: please see the edited title ?are we already not mentioning about type parameter in the return type ? Why do we need to it include the same again ?

Comment: That is the Java syntax! I'm afraid there is no other answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking why you have to write `<E>` at all, it's because this is just how Java generic syntax is defined. It won't compile otherwise since the type paramter has to be declared in this case.

If you're asking what the bound accomplishes: the most relevant thing it does is ensure that the two arguments are `Set`s of the same thing and that the return value contains the same type of thing.

Without this, you can of course still manage to union two sets of strings. After all people managed it way back in the days of Java 1.4. But the compiler can't check that for you. Without this, you can still cast the result to the right generic type, but, then you have to cast.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `<E>` let the compiler know that you are not going to specify real class name in `List<E>` like `List<String>`, but use a type variable E

Answer (score 0):

This brings you `TypeSafety`. `TypeSafety` ensures that

- Arguments passed and Return type of a function are of correct Data Type.
- A class deals with objects of correct datatype.

This is really important in large projects where you'l have to use classes and functions written by other developers. Without looking deep into function, or class definition you can pass/get objects of correct datatypes, without fear of crashing the app due to `ClassCastExceptions`.